# How is it possible to access property without "->" in c?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference

I've been learning c for a while, and let's say I thought I had a good understanding of pointers though this example is bugging me.

Let's say we have an array in which each element points to a structure. If we allocate space for two elements like in the example bellow:

```c
p = (test**)malloc(2*sizeof(test*));

p[0] = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));
p[1] = (test*)malloc(sizeof(test));
```

Here's the structure test:

```c
typedef struct {
    char *t;
    long long p;
} test;
```

And now when I assign values to the variables like below:

```c
(*p)[1].t = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
strcpy((*p)[1].t, "test");
(*p)[1].p = 10;

p[1]->t = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
p[1]->p = 20;
strcpy(p[1]->t, "test34e");
```

They fill completely different chunks of memory. How am I able to access property t at all in this example `(*p)[1].t`?

Comment: *"How am I able to access property t at all"* - You're not. `(*p)[1].t` invokes *undefined behavior*. `*p` is equivalent to `p[0]`, which is a pointer to a `test`. you then use that pointer with array indexing to access a non-existent element at effective `p[0][1]`.

Comment: `p[1]->p` is equivalent to `p[1][0].p`. `(*p)[1].p` is equivalent to `p[0][1].p`. You got the offsets in the opposite order with your two different versions of the code, due to the parentheses causing the unmodified dereference to occur before the deref at index `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been struggling with this for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
(*p[1] ).t = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
strcpy( ( *p[1] ).t, "test");
( *p[1] ).p = 10;
```

That is `p[1]` is a pointer. So you can write for example either `p[1]->t` or dereferencing the pointer and getting the pointed object of the structure type  `( *p[1] ).t`.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question in the title, though I feel like the comments on the original post have a better point and explanation of how things work.